# How to create a NSDictionnary from an array with custom cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have a `UITableView` with custom `cellView` populated with an array (cf. functs) without section. My goal is to create a search bar (which is ok) with a list index (which is the problem).
After reading a lot of documentations, I plan to use these three methods: "`numberOfSectionsInTableView`", "`sectionIndexTitlesForTableView`" and "`sectionForSectionIndexTitle`"

How to create the `NSDictionnary` of functs array with the following structure?

```
//in viewDidLoad
// Initialize the functs array
Funct *funct1 = [Funct new];
funct1.name = @"AAA";
funct1.detail = @"detail1...";
funct1.image = @"a.jpg";

Funct *funct2 = [Funct new];
funct2.name = @"BBB";
funct2.prepTime = @"detail2...";
funct2.image = @"b.jpg";

functs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:funct, funct2, nil]; //etc.

//For Index list: one section per letter
NSString *letters = @"a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z";
self.indexTitlesArray = [letters componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://www.iphonedevcentral.com/indexed-uitableview-tutorial/) you have a good tutorial with example project. It´s what you are looking for.

It´s an example for TableView indexed, but it has a good example for sections and rows

There is in this example this method very useful for you

```
static NSString *letters = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

// This method returns an array of dictionaries where each key is a letter
// and each value is a group of words corresponding to the letter. 
+ (NSArray *) wordsFromLetters {
    NSMutableArray *content = [NSMutableArray new];

    for (int i = 0; i < [letters length]; i++ ) {
       NSMutableDictionary *row = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
       char currentWord[WORD_LENGTH + 1];
       NSMutableArray *words = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

       for (int j = 0; j < WORD_LENGTH; j++ ) {
          if (j == 0) {
              currentWord[j] = toupper([letters characterAtIndex:i]);
          }
          else {
              currentWord[j] = [letters characterAtIndex:i];
          }
          currentWord[j+1] = '\0';
          [words addObject:[NSString stringWithCString:currentWord encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
       }
       char currentLetter[2] = { toupper([letters characterAtIndex:i]), '\0'};        
       [row setValue:[NSString stringWithCString:currentLetter encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] 
           forKey:@"headerTitle"];
       [row setValue:words forKey:@"rowValues"];        
       [content addObject:row];
    }

    return content;
}
```

You can take the main idea from this resource, but if you prefer, I adapted the code. I think works fine

```
    NSMutableArray *funcsArray = [NSMutableArray array];//Here you add all your functs objects
    [funcsArray addObjects: funct1, funct2...];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
    sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name"
                                                  ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] autorelease];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
    NSArray *sortedArray;
    sortedArray = [funcsArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    NSMutableArray *funcsArrayOrdered = [NSMutableArray array];//Here you add all your functs objects
    NSMutableArray *funcsIndexed = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray *letters = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSString *currentLetter = nil;

    int numItems = [funcsArrayOrdered count];

    for (Funct *functObj in funcsArrayOrdered) {
        NSLog(@"funct: %@", functObj.name);
        numItems--;
        NSString *string = userT.name;
        if (string.length > 0) {
            NSString *letter = [[string substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString];
            if ([currentLetter length] == 0) {
                currentLetter = letter;
            }
            if (![letter isEqualToString:currentLetter] || numItems == 0) {
                if ([letter isEqualToString:currentLetter] && numItems == 0) {
                    [letters addObject:functObj];
                    NSMutableDictionary *dic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
                    [dic setValue:currentLetter forKey:@"headerTitle"];
                    [dic setValue:letters forKey:@"rowValues"];
                    [funcsIndexed addObject:dic];
                    letters = [NSMutableArray array];
                }else{
                    NSMutableDictionary *dic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
                    [dic setValue:currentLetter forKey:@"headerTitle"];
                    [dic setValue:letters forKey:@"rowValues"];
                    [funcsIndexed addObject:dic];
                    letters = [NSMutableArray array];
                    [letters addObject:functObj];
                    currentLetter = letter;
                    if (numItems == 0 && [funcsArrayOrdered count] > 1) {
                        NSMutableDictionary *dic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
                        [dic setValue:currentLetter forKey:@"headerTitle"];
                        [dic setValue:letters forKey:@"rowValues"];
                        [funcsIndexed addObject:dic];
                    }
                }
            }else {
                [letters addObject:functObj];
            }
        }
    }
```

Now you will have your array of Dictionaries ordered in funcsIndexed

Comment: Please add some example code or a walkthrough instead of just a link only.

Comment: Thanks but I know this example and it’s confusing for me. It’s a method to generate words; it’s not the same structure of the array with custom cells you can see in my code. I want to generate a NSDictionnary from this array..

Comment: @SonGoku86 thanks++, dictionnary works. And I put a lot of NLog at each step of your method, so now I can understand all the process. "Top down" learning method sometimes better as "Bottom up".